# GATE - JAPE rule nested ‘contains’ operators - correct syntax

Tags: syntax, nlp, grammar, gate

I am getting errors when I try to create ‘Sentence contains’ jape rules with OR operators, i.e when a Sentence contains 1 OR 2 AND 3 OR 4:

```
(
   { 
      Sentence contains { Annotation1 | Annotation2 },  
      Sentence contains { Annotation3 | Annotation4 }
   }
)  
:temp  
-->
```

Can someone please advise on the correct syntax?

Answer (score 3):

There is no such thing like AND operator in LSH jape grammar and we cannot use OR operator inside contextual operators ie; contains and within. Instead you can code like this.

```
(
    ({Sentence contains {Annotation1}} | {Sentence contains {Annotation2}})
    ({Sentence contains {Annotation3}} | {Sentence contains {Annotation4}})
)
:temp
-->
```